# Как заставить модели мигрировать в не default базу данных

Tags: python, django

Хотелось бы узнать, как заставить модели мигрировать во вторую базу данных, определенную в settings.py?

Comment: https://django.fun/ru/docs/django/4.1/ref/databases/ тут все про БД в django

Comment: Вы же имеете в виду _изменения_, вносимые в модели (в противопоставлении с сохранением непосредственных данных в нужную БД)?

Answer (score 0):

Как указано [в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases), после `makemigrations` мы делаем `migrate` и в качестве параметра `--database` указываем имя нужной нам БД:

```
python ./manage.py migrate --database=users
```

В manage.py (и некоторых других утилитах Джанго) можно запросить `help` с интересующей командой (или без, чтобы посмотреть список некоторых доступных команд), чтобы посмотреть мини-справку о команде и принимаемых параметрах. Например,

```
python ./manage.py help migrate
```